# Can't pass value from parent to child and child to parent properly

Tags: reactjs, class, methods, components

First of all, this is my current structure

> PARENT COMPONENT

```
    class Box extends Component {
        constructor(){
            super()
            this.state={
                isLoginOpen: true,
                isRegisterOpen: false
            }
        }

        showLoginBox() {
            this.setState({
                isLoginOpen: true, 
                isRegisterOpen: false
            });
        }

        showRegisterBox() {
        this.setState({
            isRegisterOpen: true, 
            isLoginOpen: false
        });
        }
        render() {
            return  <div class="container-fluid w-100 full_div">
                <div class="container shadow">
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="row bg-white">
                        <div className={"col-sm-6 "+ (this.state.isLoginOpen? "bg-secondary": "")} 
                        >
                            <a onClick={()=>{this.showLoginBox()}} class="login-tab text-dark" href="#"><p class="text-center font-weight-bold" style={{fontSize: '25px'}}>Login</p></a>


        </div>
                    <div className={"col-sm-6 "+ (this.state.isLoginOpen? "": "bg-secondary")}>
                        <a onClick={()=>this.showRegisterBox()} class="signup-tab text-dark" href="#"><p class="active text-center font-weight-bold" style={{fontSize: '25px'}}>Sign Up</p></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    {
                        this.state.isLoginOpen?
                        <LoginBox/>
                        : <RegisterBox/>
                    }
                </div>
     }
}
```

> CHILD COMPONENT

```
class RegisterBox extends Component {
    render() {
        return  <div>
                     <p style={{marginTop: '40px'}}><a onclick="changeTab(this)" data-tab="login" className="login-tab text-dark" href="#">I already have an account</a></p> 
                    </div>;
    } 
}
```

I want to pass isLoginOpen, isRegisterOpen and showRegisterBox function value to the child component. And when I pressed **I already have an account** link on the child component I want to change the value that I get to the child component by props and sent it back to the parent. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Al Duncanson But now this problem occurs: 'props' is not defined no-undef in RegisterBox.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass those values to your child component via props like this

```
<RegisterBox
  isLoginOpen={this.state.isLoginOpen}
  isRegisterOpen={this.state.isRegisterOpen}
  showRegisterBox={this.showRegisterBox}
/>
```

Then you can call your `showRegisterBox()` function from the child component like this

```
onClick={() => props.showRegisterBox()}
```

Comment: I have done this. But now this problem occurs:                                                                                                           
   'isLoginOpen' is not defined      no-undef
   'isRegisterOpen' is not defined   no-undef
   'showRegisterBox' is not defined

Comment: I updated my answer. Did you try passing the props like this?